# Is SQLite suitable as a fairly large and secure data store?

Tags: database, sqlite

I consider use of a `SQLite` database as big data store (two hundred thousand records per year). I will do a lot of queries, a negligible amount of updates and inserts. I see that `SQLite` is very fast. Is `SQLite` is suitable and safe for this purpose ?

Comment: Do you intend this database to be single-user? What load will it have during use?

Comment: 10-30 users connected at the same time...

Comment: Then I would direct you to @Charles answer. You can consider some embeddable databases like MySQL for example. You can have the whole server as a single dll for your application without loss of any of it's features.

Comment: ...well, if ability to connect from multiple concurrent processes is a feature, I'm not so sure you can say "without any loss of its features" there. Out-of-process, non-embedded use probably makes more sense for the use case (not that I'd advise using MySQL under any circumstances whatsoever, but that's a different conversation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLite is not generally consider suitable for multiple concurrent users; it is ideal for use as an embedded, single-process store.

This is less true in cases where the clients all have the database opened read-only -- no lock contention exists in this case -- but even then, you're missing out on the caching capabilities a non-embedded, out-of-process database can provide.

Also, while it is indeed generally very fast, its query optimizer tends to lag behind that of PostgreSQL or Oracle for highly complex queries.

Finally -- in keeping with SQLite's goal to be an ideal embedded database, it does not have support for enforcing security policy (either authentication or authorization); indeed, `GRANT` and `REVOKE` are not even keywords.